# Save creator for objects created in the Django admin panel

Tags: python, django

I want to create a few objects directly in Django's admin panel, and in that object automatically save the username of the administrator that have been creating it.

Any suggestions of how to do this in the easiest way?

Cheers,

Peter

```py
class UserMessage(models.Model):
    reciever_id = models.OneToOneField(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True,
    )
    heading = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    message = models.TextField(blank=True)
    time_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    creator_id = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Comment: Got any code to show what your models.py and admin.py looks like?

Comment: Added it in the post description to make it a bit more readable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a `save_model` method to your model admin:

```py
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    if not obj.creator_id:  # if obj does not have a creator
        obj.creator_id = request.user
    super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

More details [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model)